# Multiple webforms: Show list of those user has submitted?

Tags: views, webforms, database

Is there a way to list all webform submissions user has submitted using views?

I have a site where there is hundreds of webforms. I need to create a block that contains all webforms by title current user has submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 6.Try this view export code

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'test_webform';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'webform_submissions';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->override_option('relationships', array(
  'nid' => array(
    'id' => 'nid',
    'table' => 'webform_submissions',
    'field' => 'nid',
  ),
  'uid' => array(
    'id' => 'uid',
    'table' => 'webform_submissions',
    'field' => 'uid',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'title' => array(
    'id' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'title',
    'relationship' => 'nid',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'uid_current' => array(
    'id' => 'uid_current',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'uid_current',
    'relationship' => 'nid',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->override_option('relationships', array(
  'nid' => array(
    'label' => 'Node',
    'required' => 0,
    'id' => 'nid',
    'table' => 'webform_submissions',
    'field' => 'nid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'uid' => array(
    'label' => 'User',
    'required' => 1,
    'id' => 'uid',
    'table' => 'webform_submissions',
    'field' => 'uid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'title' => array(
    'label' => 'Title',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 0,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'title',
    'relationship' => 'nid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
  ),
  'submitted' => array(
    'label' => 'Submitted',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'date_format' => 'small',
    'custom_date_format' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'submitted',
    'table' => 'webform_submissions',
    'field' => 'submitted',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'sid' => array(
    'label' => 'Sid',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'set_precision' => FALSE,
    'precision' => 0,
    'decimal' => '.',
    'separator' => ',',
    'prefix' => '',
    'suffix' => '',
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'sid',
    'table' => 'webform_submissions',
    'field' => 'sid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'uid_current' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => '1',
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'uid_current',
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'uid_current',
    'relationship' => 'uid',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Use default',
    ),
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('block_description', '');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I did pretty much similar view you have. Thanks. (Im using D7 but what the heck:) )

Comment: oh. Sure you can try the same in D7. More difference not there.